# couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U

Tags: c++, templates

I have a following function I want to use:

```
template <typename T>   
template <typename U>
TypedData<U>* convert(T min, T max) const;
```

Here's how I used it in the code:

```
const TypedData<unsigned short>* B = A->convert((float)0,(float)65535);
```

where A is the following type:

```
const TypedData<float>*
```

The complier gives me the following error and notes:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘TypedData<float>::convert(float, float) const’
note: candidate: template<class U> TypedData<U>* TypedData<T>::convert(T, T) const [with U = U; T = float]
   TypedData<U>* convert(T min, T max) const;
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U
```

I want to ask if I am using this template function correctly? and what is the reason that it gives me the error. Thanks.

Comment: `A->convert<unsigned short>(0.f, 65535.f);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `U` template parameter to `convert` as well:

```
const TypedData<unsigned short>* B = 
    A->convert<unsigned short>((float)0,(float)65535);
```

Note that this means you can avoid specifying the template parameter on the left hand side:

```
const auto* B = 
    A->convert<unsigned short>((float)0,(float)65535);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/uQiJ2r).